# Errors compiling an iOS Swift app with Firebase 5.0

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I'm trying to upgrade my Swift iOS app from Firebase 4.5 to 5.0 but I'm finding issues.

Just including *"pod 'Firebase/Core'"* in the Podfile and doing an *"import Firebase"* gives me the following error:

> ../MyApp/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/FIRNetwork.m:23:9:
>   'GoogleToolboxForMac/GTMNSData+zlib.h' file not found

This works fine with Firebase 4.5 and it also works fine with Firebase 5.0 if I do it in an Objective-C project instead of a Swift one.

Note: I'm using cocoapods 1.4 and Xcode 9.3

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. Perhaps you have a corrupted ModuleCache? Try `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`